# Localize application icon and default tile icon?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I know the trick to localize the application title for a windows phone 7 application:

http://patrickgetzmann.wordpress.com/wp7-localize/#comment-249

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Is there a (maybe similar) way to localize the application icon (I need a different icon for each language) and default tile icon (called "background image" in project settings)?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the image of the tile icon when the app first starts using ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First().Update(...). Don't know about application icon or changing things before you start, but perhaps the sample code from that msdn article would also work for additional resources, so when they ask to define resources like this one:

AppTileString, 200, "The English (United States) name of your application to be displayed in the application Tile when pinned to Start."

-that is later used in the manifest file as:

@AppResLib.dll,-200

-maybe you could also define something like

AppTileIconPath, 300, "The name of the tile icon file"

Then try using it like:

```
<BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">@AppResLib.dll,-300</BackgroundImageURI>
```

This might not work really, but it's worth a shot if you really want to localize your icons.

Comment: no, this doesn't work... (tried it) the compiler looks for a file called "@AppResLib.dll,-300"

Comment: Then no - I would say that is not possible and the only thing you can do is to localize the tile after first running the app and leave the application icon culture invariant. I would do some research on the ShellTile class.

Comment: Yes. The shell tile can be localized - just reset it on every app start. The problem is the application icon and the splashscreen image... I think there is no possibility to localize these two images...

Answer (score 1):

You can localize the app tile as described [here](http://patrickgetzmann.wordpress.com/wp7-localize/). The app icon can't be updated as far as I know. The title icon can be changed per code (ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First().Update).

You can delete the SplashScreenImage.jpg file - this resulsts that you will be navigated to the first page immediately. On the page you can display the localized content while doing your init stuff. After you are done with initialization you can navigate to your second page. To satisfy the certification requirements you'll need to remove the navigation entry for your splash screen page (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() - Mango only API).

Comment: Ok thanks. This was not an option for me. Now I will publish two apps... I have to localize the application icon and splash screen... Thanks anyway...